# How can i create border arround dynamic div?

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap 3.

here is my html code

```
<div class="border-box">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="padding-top">Record</div>
        <div>Record</div>
        <div>Record</div>
        <div>Record</div>
        <div>Record</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
        <div>record1</div>
        <div>record2</div>
        <div>record3</div>
        <div>record4</div>
        <div>record5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.border-box {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Here I set fix height to the box, but when the content of record5 increases, it goes out of the box. I want to make it work dynamically.

Comment: If you set the height of of `.border-box` it will never adjust dynamically to fit its children contents....there will alway be an overflow of content.....take out that height rule and you will notice how the height dynamically adjusts

Comment: I have included height as temporary solution. and if i remove height from css class, it wont create box, it creates just single line border.

Comment: dont set any height property like height, min-height and max-height. Add overflow:auto to .border-box

Answer (score 1):

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjg80rej/)

HTML

```
<div class="border-box">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <div class="padding-top">Record</div>
    <div>Record</div>
    <div>Record</div>
    <div>Record</div>
    <div>Record</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
    <div>record1</div>
    <div>record2</div>
    <div>record3</div>
    <div>record4</div>
    <div>record5</div>
     <div>record1</div>
    <div>record2</div>
    <div>record3</div>
    <div>record4</div>
    <div>record5</div>
     <div>record1</div>
    <div>record2</div>
    <div>record3</div>
    <div>record4</div>
    <div>record5</div>
     <div>record1</div>
    <div>record2</div>
    <div>record3</div>
    <div>record4</div>
    <div>record5</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.border-box {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 margin:30px 15px 15px 15px;
 min-height:150px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="border-box">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="padding-top">Record</div>
        <div>Record</div>
        <div>Record</div>
        <div>Record</div>
        <div>Record</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
        <div>record1</div>
        <div>record2</div>
        <div>record3</div>
        <div>record4</div>
        <div>record5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.border-box{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  //this will trigger the overflow
  overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

Comment: then that time you will use javascript to get the height of the box and add some height to the the default height

Answer (score 0):

just change `height` to `min-height`

BTW, you can write all this with much less lines:

```
.border-box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 30px 15px 15px;
  min-height: 150px;
}
```